# Suggestion in MySQLTuner

Tags: mysql, mysqltuner

Suggestion in MySQLTuner
Hi i have run the MySQLTuner - perl and i take

Security Recommendations

```
Warning: Using unique option prefix pass instead of password is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
Warning: Using unique option prefix pass instead of password is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
```

Performance Metrics

```
[--] Up for: 22m 28s (463K q [344.006 qps], 1K conn, TX: 857M, RX: 90M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 99% / 1%
[--] Total buffers: 168.0M global + 2.8M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 583.2M (1% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/463K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 12% (19/151)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 8.0M/146.0M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (184M cached / 55K reads)
[!!] Query cache is disabled
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (34 temp sorts / 738K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 543
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 23% (30K on disk / 131K total)
[!!] Thread cache is disabled
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 0% (400 open / 58K opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (759/500K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 99% (842K immediate / 842K locks)
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/92.3M
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
```

Recommendations

```
Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    Adjust your join queries to always utilize indexes
    Set thread_cache_size to 4 as a starting value
    Increase table_open_cache gradually to avoid file descriptor limits
    Read this before increasing table_open_cache over 64:
```

Variables to adjust:

```
query_cache_size (>= 8M)
join_buffer_size (> 128.0K, or always use indexes with joins)
thread_cache_size (start at 4)
table_open_cache (> 400)
```

The server has 48gb ran and i7 cpu
In my.cnf i have

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=500000
local-infile=0
```

Any suggestion's ?

Comment: Suggestions about what? You've had a lot of suggestions from the tool. What's your question?

Comment: Yes, the suggestion is "don't use tuning scripts."  Use default values unless you have a specific reason to change them.  Change only values you understand, and only one thing at a time.

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the last version of mysqltuner on github.

Mysqltuner says:
MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate

You should use mysqltuner after a longer time frame.